# C# Change text on click event

Tags: c#, mouseclick-event

I have a field that currently changes text on a mouse click. This field is on multiple pages of my report, but clicking it only changes the text for that page. Here is my code for that:

```
 const string sShowDetail2 = "Show Cumulative";
 const string sHideDetail2 = "Hide Cumulative";
 ArrayList expandedValues2 = new ArrayList();


    // This function returns a value indicating whether a certain  
    // category's details should be expanded. 

    bool ShouldShowDetail2(int CategoryID)
    {
        return expandedValues2.Contains(CategoryID);

    }



    private void lbShowHide2_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        XRLabel label = (XRLabel)sender;

        if (ShouldShowDetail2((int)label.Tag))
        {
            label.Text = sHideDetail2;
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = sShowDetail2;
        }
    }

    private void lbShowHide2_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Obtain the category's ID stored in the label's Tag property. 
        int index = (int)e.Brick.Value;

        // Determine whether the current category's details are shown. 
        bool showDetail2 = ShouldShowDetail2(index);

        // Toggle the visibility of the category's details. 
        if (showDetail2)
        {
            expandedValues2.Remove(index);
        }
        else
        {
            expandedValues2.Add(index);
        }
```

Now I have another field that I need to simply toggle all instances of the field(every page) on click. I do not need it to read the tag of the particular one I clicked because it will be changing all of them at the same time. My problem is that I don't know how to get them all to change on mouse click. How could I modify the code above to change all instances of the label?

Comment: So are you saying you want to change the label on multiple windows forms based on what happens on one form.  Is that correct?

Comment: do a foreach loop on Controls checking within the loop if the control type i s`XRLabel` and if so create an instance of that Label and change the label.text also make sure to create a Static variable that you can access at the application level if needed

Comment: @Jamie Yes right now it only changes the one that is clicked. However, I am adding another label that will display "All" or "None" and toggle all instances of the label.

Comment: @DJKRAZE where would the loop go. Would it be easier to keep a count of # of mouse clicks and toggle the lable.text based on whether it is odd/even?

Comment: I will paste an Example in the Answer section on what you could do it's up to you from there to mess around / experiment with it and do what ever you see fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you could try

```
private void ChangeXRLabels(Control control)
{
    foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
    {
         XRLabel label = childControl as XRLabel;
         if(label != string.Empty)
            label.Text = "Your Text Value goes Here";
         else if(childControl.Controls.Count > 0)
             ChangeXRLabels(childControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could even keep the value in a List<T> and create 2 fields in the List<T> or an Array, etc and on load of each page you can run / perform that method based on some condition the options are limitless

Comment: This gives me an error saying that I cannot convert a control to and xrlabel. Also operator != cannot be applied to operands of type xrlabel and string.

Comment: Awesome.. glad I could be of assistance